# Three.js making site very slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, webgl, effects

I have been using the very cool Three.js based effect released in this github library https://github.com/Ramotion/aquarelle in my website.

The effect looks great, the problem is the dramatic impact on performance. I just need to use it for the beginning intro, the effect is then removed and it is not needed again.

Despite removing the canvas and the animation having finished, performance of the whole site is permanently reduced. If I reload without the effect performance returns to its normal state.

For reference the canvas and relevant images are inside a React element. When i say removing the effect I am calling

```
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode)
```

from inside the react element containing the canvas and aquarelle object.

How can i use the aquarelle effect for the beginning and then completely remove it from memory? That is close any Three.js items, clear everything and effectively return the site to a state if the effect had never been run?

Thanks

Comment: have you called the `Aquarelle.stop()` method?

Comment: yes, unfortunately it doesn't help, though in the aquarelle readme it does stay stop does "stop and reset animation". Nothing about completely deleting it.  
'delete aquarelle' doesn't work either :/